# Loading drawing program through emacs

Tags: emacs, drawing, latex

I'm looking for a way to integrate a drawing program with emacs. I often write lecture notes in LaTeX using emacs. The problem is that when the presenter draws a diagram I start to scramble to draw out the diagram, save it, and type the location into my TeX file in a reasonable time.

Is it possible to set up emacs such that when I press a key combination a drawing program will load (e.g. pinta) and once I draw the diagram, the file will automatically save in the folder of the emacs file and the name of the file will be inserted into emacs through

```
\includegraphics{File_Name}
```

If this feature is too difficult to implement please let me know as well (I'm also more than happy to try to out variations of this idea).

**EDIT in response to comments**: My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 and the absolute path my drawing program is /usr/bin/pinta

Comment: Here is an outline:  (I.) Create a blank image file with your favorite program, e.g., pinta.  (II.) Save it in a form file directory -- e.g., `/Users/HOME/forms/my-empty-image.png`.  The Emacs function will do the following:  (1) copy `/Users/HOME/forms/my-empty-image.png` to the location of your notes file, with a minibuffer prompt that permits you to edit the name and confirm saving; (2) the new file name is automatically inserted into your notes at the correct location; (3) Use `start-process` to open up that file in your favorite external editor.  Draw, save, exit, and your done.

Comment: Please specify your OS so that someone can handle your `start-process` phase.  In addition, please provide the absolute path of your favorite image program, e.g., pinta.

Comment: @lawlist: Thanks for your ideas, that sounds terrific! I updated my question with the information you requested.

Comment: There's also `artist-mode` :)

Comment: @JeffDror -- Can you do me a favor please and test whether this snippet will work on your system without any additional arguments -- we are just trying to open a pinta file from Emacs using pinta.  `M-x eval-expression RET (start-process "open-in-pinta" "*test-output-buffer*" "/usr/bin/pinta" my-new-filename) RET` You will need to insert a name of **an already existing** pinta file instead of `my-new-filename` -- e.g., substitute `my-new-filename` with something like `"/tmp/my-already-existing.png"`.  If you know of any additional command-line arguments (if applicable), please let me know.

Comment: @lawlist: I just tested it and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initial Draft -- Not Fully Tested -- Prototype** (June 22, 2014):  The following is a first rough draft / not fully tested protype of the concept function idea outlined in the comment beneath the question by the original poster.  Because @lawlist does not have an Ubantu OS set-up, or pinta installed, the last part of the function is untested -- i.e., `(start-process "open-in-pinta" nil "/usr/bin/pinta" my-new-filename)`.  If there are additional command-line arguments needed for that `start-process` statement to work on Ubantu, please let me know.  The variable `form-graphic-file` needs to have the absolute path to an **already existing** blank file created with the `pinta` program -- that file should be saved in a forms directory somewhere chosen by the user.  The function `copy-graphic` is a modification of the function `dired-do-create-files`.

**TODO**:

- Verify functionality of the `start-process` statement.
- Convert variable `form-file-graphic` from a `list` to a `string` format and revise `copy-graphic` function accordingly.

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; \includegraphics{File_Name}

(defvar form-file-graphic "~/forms/my-empty-image.ora"
  "Absolute path to existing blank graphic file previously created with `pinta'.")

(defun copy-graphic (target)
  "This function is a modification of `dired-do-create-files'."
  (interactive
   (list (expand-file-name (read-file-name "Copy to: " nil "diagram.ora"))))
  (copy-file form-file-graphic target)
  (insert "\\includegraphics{" (file-relative-name target) "}\n")
  (start-process "open-in-pinta" nil "/usr/bin/pinta" target))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! On my system I find that when I evaluate copy-graphic there are no errors but when I run it (through `M-x copy-graphic`) I get "symbol's function definition is void: dired-make-relative". I suspect this is because I was supposed to define my-new-filename somewhere, but I'm not sure where?

Comment: That's because lawlist copied a lot of irrelevant stuff from dired-do-create-files.  I stripped the code down to something simpler, and guaranteed 100% untested.  Some animals may have purred during this operation.

Comment: @Stefan -- thank you for helping us to create a working function that is written in a more efficient manner -- greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: @Stefan and lawlist: It works perfectly. Thank you very much for making my long desired emacs fantasy come true!